# How do I convert Int/Decimal to float in C#?

Tags: c#, casting, floating-point

How does one convert from an int or a decimal to a float in C#?

I need to use a float for a third-party control, but I don't use them in my code, and I'm not sure how to end up with a float.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You can just do a cast

```
int val1 = 1;
float val2 = (float)val1;
```

or

```
decimal val3 = 3;
float val4 = (float)val3;
```

Comment: Can't we just do `float val2 = val1;`?

Answer (score 52):

The same as an int:

```
float f = 6;
```

Also here's how to programmatically convert from an int to a float, and a single in C# is the same as a float:

```
int i = 8;
float f = Convert.ToSingle(i);
```

Or you can just cast an int to a float:

```
float f = (float)i;
```

Comment: And there i was looking for Convert.ToFloat() +1

Comment: also +1 for toSingle

Comment: For some reason (float) didn't work for me, but Convert.ToSingle() did the trick! +1

Answer (score 5):

You don't even need to cast, it is implicit.

```
int i = 3;

float f = i;
```

A full list/table of implicit numeric conversions can be seen here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx

Comment: but you do need a cast for decimal to float

Answer (score 2):

It is just:

```
float f = (float)6;
```