# How to cast int to float in C#?

Tags: c#, casting

I want to write this equation:

```
1+(2/n!)+(3/n!)+...+(n/n!),
```

But the result is always equal to 1.
Where is the wrong code?
My code:

```
Console.Write("Please Enter Your Number: ");

int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

int fact = 1;

for (int i = num; i > 1; i--)
{
    fact *= i;
}

Console.WriteLine("Fact= " + fact);

float result = 1;

for (int i = 2; i >= num; i++)
{
    result += (i / fact);

}
Console.WriteLine("Result= " + result);

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: You use `(float) x` to cast `x` to a `float`.

Comment: Remember, in C# (and C and Java and several other languages): `int / int -> int`. That is, the *operands* determine the division operation mode.

Comment: The question isn't "how", it's *where*. And "where" is, "before you do any math with it that ought to be floating point math".

Comment: I test it but not correct!

Comment: yes I  made a mistake.

Comment: Ignoring flat out non-working loop code standard [int to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042099/how-do-i-convert-int-decimal-to-float-in-c) provides the answer. Note that it is well known fact that [factorial is simply 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222207/why-computing-factorial-of-realtively-small-numbers-34-returns-0) - so you really should be getting "divide by zero" exceptions instead.

Comment: The reason is your condition in for loop in wrong. And there is some adjustment to make the result float.

try this below code. 

            for (int i = 2; i <= num; i++)
            {
                result += ((i * 1.0f)/ fact);

            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this does not loop

```
for (int i = 2; i >= num; i++)
```

If you had traced it out in debug it would have been obvious

```
<=
```

On the implicate cast this `(i / fact)` is probably performed before the cast so cast fact to float.  (float)fact.

You don't have an int / decimal

You could use decimal rather than float

Comment: 'for (int i = num; i >1; i--)'

Comment: it's correct loop.

Comment: Q LOKO open your eyes

Comment: Come on down vote what is the problem?