# How do I shift the decimal point in C#

Tags: c#, data-conversion

If I have an int equal to 8675309 what would be the best/quickest way to convert that into a float equal to 0.8675309f?

### Examples:

---

input as an int: 8675309

output as a float: 0.8675309

---

input as an int: 4234512

output as a float: 0.4234512

---

input as an int: 56

output as a float: 0.56

---

input as an int: 123456

output as a float: 0.123456

---

input as an int: 654321

output as a float: 0.654321

---

I've tried mapping the outputs to a value between 0 and 1, but for an RNG setup it tends to have an average of .64 which isn't ideal.

I've used Tanh, Cos, Sin, and other functions to get it mapped, but it seems as though I'm really only wanting to get the exact number with a decimal at the beginning of it so the accuracy stays the same.

I could divide by a large number I suppose, but it wouldn't be consistent as the size of the number would have to change as the RNG output changed in size.

I really don't know why this doesn't have enough information in it. In the first line it is clear what EXACTLY I am looking to do. How can someone be more specific than that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert Int/Decimal to float in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042099/how-do-i-convert-int-decimal-to-float-in-c)

Comment: @gunr2171 It doesn't, please read the question

Comment: So then also do multiplication?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched? please **edit** your question to include more information.



please also read [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Welcome. Dirty but quick: `float.TryParse($"0.{integer}", out float value);`. Not sure what's your goal here, because that's not really how to 'Convert an integer to a float', that's something different.

Comment: Have you tried `i / 10000000f`? If not, why not? If you did, why did it not suffice?

Comment: no. That will only return the same number with a different data type. I need the decimal to be at the front of everything making the number less than 1.

Comment: "Needs details or clarity" really? IMO it's perfectly clear

Comment: based on your edit, i'm pretty sure that this is a typical X-Y-problem, and what you're really trying to _achieve_ is a random number between 0 and 1?

Comment: essentially, though If possible I'd like the exact number im manipulating to end in the equivalent as I structured above.

Comment: @Fr0z3n5un Does my answer from 9 mins ago answer your original question?

Comment: Would you like 29 to become 0.29? If so then be aware that if you generate random numbers between 0 and, say, 10.000.000, you will not get a uniform distribution in your result. Experimentation shows me that the resulting average will lie around 0.55, and not 0.5.

Comment: Im currently testing it, initially it worked, but i want to make sure it holds up with various number sizes :)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen my rng in theory should never put out numbers that low, they are fairly large typically

Comment: I think the problem @LasseV.Karlsen is pointing to is that with this projection your distribution lies between 0.1 and 1 and not between 0 and 1!! (well theoretically it could draw exactly 0 but you can understand what I mean), any value that would've mapped between 0 and 0.1 you instead map to higher values resulting in your uneven distribution. This is also why people are talking about X-Y problem and you not providing enough information. You've said nothing about what you're actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you'd do this on paper is:

1. Find the number of digits in 8675309
2. Divide by `10^(number of digits)`

You can find the number of digits when written as base 10 either by formatting it as a string and counting the characters (bad), or by taking the log to the base 10 and rounding it up (good):

```
int input = 8675309;
int numDigits = (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10(input));
```

Then divide this by `10^numDigits`:

```
float result = input / MathF.Pow(10, numDigits);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: OP talks about wanting a distribution between 0 and 1 (with an implied average of 0.5?), but I think this will skip any values in the interval (0, 0.1). Even though OP asks for this (my only conclusion would that there is a contradiction in what OP requests, and I assume that's why people asked for clarification). So even though I'm normally a big fan of your answers and comments, in this case I feel like you might not have provided OP with what he actually needs.

Comment: @Knoop In fairness, I answered before their edit which added the extra information dump. People tried and failed to make progress in the comments on the OP, so I don't fancy my chances! This answers the spec laid down in the first half of the question so I'm going to leave it up (perhaps others may actually have this problem as specified), but if someone else manages to work out what OP *needs*, feel free to answer, and they'll be welcome to take the green tick